# how to maintain a inactive TCP connection in linux C?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, network-programming

if a TCP client establishes a TCP connection with a TCP server. Then the TCP client never sends any packet to the server.

First, I roughly know firewalls near the TCP server may send a RST to it. or there is a keep-alive timeout which force the TCP connection end. But I don't know exactly what will happen？ can anyone explain a bit?

Second, Is it possible to maintain this TCP connection unless I want it to end?

I just hope the TCP server can keep this TCP connection on its TCP stack. But I don't want the TCP client to be involved, I don't want the client to send KEEP-ALIVE message. I don't want any other third-party entity involved. I don't care whether the TCP client lost the connection or not. I just hope that when I'm writing the source codes of TCP server, the source codes can manage to maintain the TCP connection on the server.

Note: my programming language is LINUX C

thanks!

Comment: That's an odd use of TCP. Why would you want connections on a server, and not care if clients disconnected? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, it is odd. I'm doing a research work, and I want to split TCP.

Comment: So you want your server to maintain TCP connections even if clients drop out? Get the scissors and cut the cable. Otherwise `FIN`s from dying clients, or `RST`s from intermediate devices timing out on no flow, will kill your research.

Comment: `FIN` from dying client is no problem. I can handle that well. I'm just afraid the `RST` from nodes. For `RST` I can just use iptables to filter it. Any other possibilities that may kill the tcp connection?

Comment: @misteryes In that case the machine would just think the connection is open. If you try to send anything on it, it would eventually time out from lack of acks, and if a firewall or similar has timed out the connection ,you'll not receive anything from it either. And you can't tell the difference of an RST from a firewall from an RST from a client.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable keepalive at your end it will send periodic probes, and if they aren't answered your end will reset the connection. Keepalive is off by default, so if you don't enable it at your end it won't happen from your end.

However the peer can still enable it at his end, in which case his end will behave as above, and you can neither prevent nor even detect it.

The rest of the question doesn't make sense. The client or a firewall can send an RST at any time for any of a number of reasons. You can't prevent that, and you can't ignore it in the code. If there is a connection reset anywhere for any reason, there is no connection to maintain.

If you don't want TCP, use something else.

Comment: if I don't enable keepalive on the tcp server, what will happen?

Comment: if I enable the keepalive, will the keepalive probe include sequence number and check the sequence number?

Comment: If you don't enable keepalive at the server, it won't send probes, so it won't expect responses, so it won't reset the connection in their absence. That is a logical consequence of what is already stated in my answer, The keepalive probe consists of an ACK for an already received sequence number.